# Ajax Files browser ; What are the good practices

Tags: php, jquery, jstree, filebrowse

I'm working on a file browser (a very ligth file manager if you prefer) based on PHP and Javascript.

I'm building a treeview with my folders :

```
<ul id="treeview">
    <li><a href="#">Folder 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Folder 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each link represent a folder. What I want to do from here is loading the content of a folder after cliking on it.

I have this PHP code to do that :

```
public function getContent($path)
{
    //fetch the content of $path directory
}
```

I have this JS code to handle the events :

```
$('#treeview a').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var folder = //here : get the path
    loadContentInPanel(folder);
});
```

But I don't know how to get the path of the clicked folder safely. Should I add it directly in attribute like this? :

```
<li><a href="root/folder2/folder2.1/"> Folder 2.1</a></li>
```

Ideally I would like the path be not visible( not clearly readable at least) to the end user. I was thinking to build link with base64_encode() but is that a good idea ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already giving away the path to the folder with your treeview, I don't see a problem with adding it to the actual element.

```
<li><a href="root/folder2/folder2.1/"> Folder 2.1</a></li>
```

Will be in

```
<ul id="treeview">//root
    <li><a href="#">Folder 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 2</a> //folder2
```

Perform all your security checks at the "getContent" function and you'll be fine.

Comment: yes you are right about the path. Just giving the arborescence but not the full path seems to be a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If you just need simple obfuscation (any dev would be able to get the real path in no time) then base64_encode() is the simplest way (provided your path are no longer than 600-700 chars).

By the way remember that security should not be based on obfuscation but on solid access checks to the resources you're jealous of.